# Transferring units in Age of Wonders campaigns

Tags: age-of-wonders

In Age of Wonders (the first one, with Inioch), when playing a campaign, a player can choose what heroes/units/items to bring to the next map, along with some gold/mana.

**Is there a way to influence the choices, say, offer certain items/units**? I keep getting bowmen proposed for transfer, while I have the nicest leveled priest I'd love to have with me.

*I thought it was the leader's party, but that didn't turn out to be true.*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to influence it. When you win a map, you get a selection of your 8 "strongest" units to choose from. It seems like the computer thinks of your highest-levelled units as strongest, and chooses randomly if various strongest-levelled units are present.

So you better just save right before your final battle (so you can go back if you find yourself not being ready for this battle yet), disband all of your unneeded units, and save again (so if you make a mistake during combat, you don't have to make the disbanding work again).

You cannot be suggested to take disbanded units into the next map (as they are neutral now and no longer belong to you), so it works. Tested and helped me to take my gold medal Pony Riders into the second map of the Keepers campaign on my first run instead of an army of Halfling Clerics that I used to heal my army of Pony Riders.

Answer (score 0):

There's good news and bad news.

The good news is you can influence the units offered.

The bad news is it is still random.

I saved a mission just before winning, and repeatedly reloading and instantly winning (cheat) gave the same result of units offered. However, if I moved even a single unit to a different location on the map before winning, the units offered after the mission would change. It did not matter if a unit was with my leader, as the cavalry always was in the images below.

So if you really need a unit to make it to the next mission, you would need to save as soon as possible before winning and try doing different movement to influence the offerings. Nothing can guarantee a specific unit.

[image]

Comment: This answer is blatantly wrong; see my answer above. You can influence the units you take to the next chapter very easily.